# Django get related object's QuerySet inside annotate

Tags: python, django

## My Models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #Unnecessary

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_comments")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="post_comments")
    liked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="liked_comments")
    disliked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True related_name="disliked_comments")
    #Unnecessary
```

## What I Have

Normally, i use this code to make my comment objects have the attribute "`voting`" and order them by that attribute.

```
comments = models.Comment.objects.filter(post=post).annotate(voting=Count("liked_users")-Count("disliked_users")).order_by("-voting")
```

But when I want to query posts, I can't reach their comments:

## What I Want

I want my QuerySet "`posts`" to have an attribute for every single post, called "`best_3_comments`". Which is a QuerySet of comments of them ordered by their `voting`'s.

Can I achieve this without querying all of the comments everytime I query posts?

```
posts = models.Post.objects.annotate(
        best_3_comments = get_query_of_the_posts_comments("post_comments").annotate(
            voting=Count("liked_users")-Count("disliked_users")
            ).order_by("-voting")[:3]
        )
```

What function(s) can i use to get query of the post's comments, and how should i approach this ? I'm completely open to new ideas of ways to do what I want to achieve, I couldn't find which function and how to use for it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Likely `voting=Count("liked_users")-Count("disliked_users")` will always return `0`, since you make a JOIN on both tables, and the counts will thus in essence always count `dislikes * likes`, and thus return `0`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, I didn't get it, it does work when querying comment objects and orders them by the voting attribute. it is number of users liked minus number of users disliked, and you can't like and dislike a comment at the same time, I made the like and dislike functions remove user from the other field if is in it. What can i do to get query of the post's "post_comments" (comment_set) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I would like to share it for those in future looking for a way to solve their problems similar to mine.

```
posts = models.Post.objects.all() # The QuerySet You Want To Use

for post in posts:
    post.best_3_comments = models.Comment.objects.filter(post=post).annotate(voting=Count("liked_users")-Count("disliked_users")).order_by("-voting")[:3]
```

The solution is iterating over our QuerySet, assigning an attribute for all of them which contains a QuerySet.